# Unable to upload or access vsftpd directory after upgrade from trusty to xenial

Tags: server, upgrade, permissions, vsftpd

This is a strange situation.  Recently upgraded my 14.04.5 Trusty system to 16.04.2 Xenial. Everything is working fine except ftp.  I can ftp to the upgraded system and log in, but I can't see any of the directories so I can't upload or download.  Directory permissions haven't changed and I am still using the original vsftpd.conf so I can't figure out what is happening.

Comment: It looks like it's a firewall issue.  If I shut down the firewall, I can connect and see the directories.  If I enable the firewall, I can connect, but that's about it... I can't see directories and I can't transfer files.  I uninstalled and reinstalled vsftpd, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Still struggling with this.  Doesn't ANYBODY have any ideas?  I did a complete uninstall of gufw and ufw, then reinstalled both.  When I checked, there were no rules set, so I added the rule for FTP, but still can't connect.  I can only connect if I shut down the firewall altogether.  WHY??